# Using the "#" symbol from "boisik" font family

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I was trying to use the hash symbol (#) from `boisik` font family on pdfLaTex (In Overleaf). That is, I want to use `\hash` instead of `\#` in my document. But the problem is that if I use `\usepackage(boisik)`, the font in my whole document is getting changed.

I saw [different answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) to this kind of problems, but all those answers are probably meant for some other font families, e.g. `mathabx`,`fourier` etc., but I am unable to implement what those answers say.

Can anyone please help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This migh help you: [writing a section in a specific style and typeface after setting a new (separate) standard typeface](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291417/90202).

Comment: @Jojo , thanks for your suggestion. It worked too. I got to know about the ```libertine``` package too !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want that, because the Boisik fonts are only available in bitmap format.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\hash}{{\fontfamily{bsk}\selectfont\#}}

\begin{document}

The normal \# and the Boisik one \hash

\end{document}
```

[image]

A magnified version:

[image]

You could obviate the problem by choosing very high resolution:

```latex
\pdfpkmode{dpdfezzz}
\pdfpkresolution=8000

\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\hash}{{\fontfamily{bsk}\selectfont\#}}

\begin{document}

The normal \# and the Boisik one \hash

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It helped.